# Form a string from a data frame column

Tags: r

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | A |
| 102 | B |
| 103 | C |

So I have a data frame (see above) with an id for each competition. I want to use these ids to form a string that I then can use for an API request. The request requires for the ids to be in the following form:

101%2C102%2C103

Any ideas of how I might achieve this would be very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paste0 function with the collapse parameter returns a character object from the vector (102, 102, 103...) with each item separated by the supplied string.

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(101, 102, 103))

paste0(df$id, collapse="%2C")

[1] "101%2C102%2C103"
```